# Open json file in jade + express

Tags: express, pug

I'm new to jade and express so I might not be getting things right, I'm trying to open a json file and use its data in my file by all I get is an undefined variable, I do get the right content in the index.js but not in the html render.

I used a solution found in here but problem remain the same, my variable is never defined.

in index.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    require('fs').readFile('public/data/cocktails.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
res.render('index');
});
```

in the index.jade

```
- console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're really close. You're reading the file and parsing the JSON, but you're not passing it to `res.render`. To modify your code just a little:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  require('fs').readFile('public/data/cocktails.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    // This is the changed line!
    res.render('index', obj);
  });
});
```

Now you should be able to use the data in `public/data/cocktails.json` in your Jade view.

Also, one last thing to note: Jade has been renamed to [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) for copyright reasons. A good thing to keep in mind for the future if Jade suddenly stops working!

Answer (score 1):

your jade and router file don't share variables...
I'm assuming you're using express, if so, you pass the variable to the res.render function.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
res.render('index',{obj:obj});
```

it can now be accessed in the index.jade file as the variable obj.

```
- console.log(obj)
```